# What is the code or property to move a subform while the user tabs over to the next control?

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties

I have a continuous subform with 30 headers. Since there are so many headers, the subform is cut off the screen and needs to be scrolled horizontally over to view the fields and active controls as the user is typing.

I want to be able to hit tab or enter and the subform or horizontal scrolling moves along with the active control so we can currently see the field we are in.

I had this working before I believe as a default but now I cannot get the setting back. I am not sure if it's a property or would I have to fix this problem in the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am assuming when you say "30 headers", you mean 30 columns, correct? Is the subform in Datasheet view?

Comment: @kismert No, this is not in Datasheet view. It's in continuous view. And yes, 30 headers which are all different sizes but still 1/3 of the headers and fields are cut off.

Comment: I tried tabbing around on a continuous form in one of my databases, and it scrolled horizontally to show the active control, no problem. Do you have horizontal scrollbars enabled?

Comment: @kismert that's the problem. I know that when you create a continuous subform, it works by default. I do believe I messed with something and possibly disabled it. The scrollbars are enabled but only move if I click and drag on them, not when I tab to the next control.

Comment: Certain versions of Access (update 1707 to Access 2016) are known to cause scrolling issues. Does this apply to you?

Comment: A test: make a new continuous form, and copy all of the old controls to it. Does it scroll the way you want? If so, you can compare the two forms and find the change that caused the problem.